# How to limit sql server table to 100,000 rows max

Tags: sql-server

I know that this is impossible but still need a solution.
I need to limit the number of rows in a table to 100,000 - having rows moderated by a datetime2 column. Newest rows come in, the old ones disappear.
This way I will not have to write a batch task that periodically deletes the unneeded rows.

Also the solution needs to be deployed into a production environment where there are 1,000,000 rows already and it will have to delete the existing ones.

Comment: You can use a trigger or a job scheduled to be executed every XX min/hours/...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best solution is to "write a batch task that periodically deletes the unneeded rows."

Answer (score 1):

What practical reason is there for a 100K limit, other than to create a self-inflicted wound? What is the daily record add? You could delete/prune data by day if you have some flexibility by date range. You could also use a view to select the top 100K and take care of deletions at your leisure. Otherwise, you're looking at expensive (because of being repeated so many times) queries/delete/inserts to make room for new records while purging the oldest.

Answer (score 0):

The questions of Steve Callan are right. But if you have to face it anyway,
supposing you have an IDENTITY(1,1), you have to keep the last 100,000 rows, so the delete should be something like this:

```
with to_keep as (
select top 100000 id from [mytable] order by id desc)
, to_delete as (
select id from [mytable]
except
select id from cte)
delete m
from [mytable] as m
inner inner join to_delete on m.id = cte.id
```

try this as a job every 30 sec. I prefer so instead of a trigger.
But this can't give you centancy to have always exact 100k rows.

Answer (score 0):

With the obvious caveat that this is a bad idea, there is a simple solution that doesn't involve a batch job. Use an INSTEAD OF INSERT trigger that determines how many rows it needs to remove to allow the insert and remain under the cap, performs the delete then allows the insert. You can see a [working example here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=1461dd01783e38740e8ca37b7d006c49).

The trigger:

```
CREATE TRIGGER trLimit100 ON LimitTo100
INSTEAD OF INSERT
AS
BEGIN
  DECLARE @InsertCount INT, @CurrentRows INT, @DeleteCount INT
  
  SELECT @InsertCount = COUNT(*) FROM INSERTED -- How many rows are being inserted
  SELECT @CurrentRows = COUNT(*) FROM LimitTo100 -- How many current rows
  
  SELECT @DeleteCount = (@CurrentRows - 100) + @InsertCount -- how many rows need to be deleted to make room for the new rows under the cap.
  
  IF (@DeleteCount > 0) -- If rows need to be removed, then remove them in date ascending order
  BEGIN
    DELETE FROM LimitTo100 
    WHERE Id IN (SELECT TOP (@DeleteCount) Id FROM LimitTo100 ORDER BY Date ASC)
  END
  
-- Perform the insert
  INSERT INTO LimitTo100 (Date, DataValue)
  SELECT i.Date, i.DataValue
  FROM INSERTED i
END
```